1990s movie with drive-by cafe attack set on a crossroad in North Africa
I am trying to identify a movie I saw in the 1990s or early 2000s, an intelligent, well-made English-language thriller/suspense/action film with multi-national locations. The opening scene involves a drive-by attack on a cafe on a dusty street, possibly with a street market or a lot of shop stalls in Morocco or someplace similar (North Africa or the Middle East). 
We see a car approach the crossroad and turn down the street toward the cafe. Lots of suspense as it approaches. Then the climax: a drive-by attack in which a young local girl is shot, instead of the intended target, an large, unpleasant man, possibly a drug dealer.
The movie ends with this same shooting, but possibly with a different outcome, or at least a different interpretation of the events.  In between is the fast-paced, suspenseful story involving some kind of criminal activity (drugs or terrorism or politics--I just don't remember) and some deception on the part of the girl. I think she is in love with a driver or henchman of the intended victim. The hero--played by someone like George Clooney or Brad Pitt (but not actually either of those actors)--has to figure it all out, which he eventually does.
This movie is similar in mood to "Babel" (interconnected stories, Morocco) and the opening scene is similar to "The Assignment" (cafe attack). Like those two films, it is well-written and intelligent, not just a sequence of special effects. It's not a franchise--not a Bourne film or James Bond, and doesn't involve superheroes or any kind of Sci-Fi or fantasy elements. 
I've been trying to identify it for several months now without success. It's driving me crazy. If anyone can help, I would be ever so grateful!

It sounds like the movie Rendition (2007)

A CIA analyst questions his assignment after witnessing an unorthodox interrogation at a secret detention facility outside the US.





Thank you, Amina! It is indeed "Rendition"! Mystery solved! For a number of reasons I had convinced myself it was a movie from the 1990s and so had not been considering later films, but this is indeed the movie I had been seeking. I am so relieved. Again my thanks to you and to this site for all your help. How do I "close" this inquiry?
